# Pytorch: Which class weights I need to pass to BCELoss

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, pytorch

I'm trying to build a Resnet model with ***Sigmoid*** with ***BCELoss*** lose. Since my data is imbalance, I guess I need to use "class weights" as an argument for the "***BCELoss***". But which weight I should pass, is it for the positive (with 1) or negative (with 0). Of course, when I tried to pass 2 weight, for Sigmoid model, I got above error:
output with shape [64, 1] doesn't match the broadcast shape [64, 2].

```
class_weights2=[postive/(negtive+postive),negtive/(negtive+postive)]
print(class_weights2)
# [0.3135668226071564, 0.6864331773928436]
class_weights=torch.tensor(class_weights2,dtype=torch.float)
lossFunc= torch.nn.BCELoss(class_weights)
```

and this the model:

```
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=False)

model.fc = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(
        in_features=2048,
        out_features=1
    ),
    torch.nn.Sigmoid()
)
```

Comment: Can you print and share the two tensors that have a shape mismatch? Sometimes you end up with a 2D tensor that is actually a 1D tensor in disguise. For example `x = torch.tensor([[1], [2], [3]])` is of shape `torch.Size([3, 1])`. If you use [`torch.squeeze()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.squeeze.html) with argument `dim=-1` you will get a tensor `[1, 2, 3]` of shape `torch.Size([3])` which has removed the last dimension which had no data.